# A nice way to change the anchor "position"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been experimenting with building a new site...
http://zergxost.com/test.html - it will take quite some time to load fully, that's the price of free hostings...

It's raw, the hover buttons don't preload, the logo on top is a sketch, etc etc... But that's not my problem - there's just one thing I actually need help in sorting out - the anchors.

You see, if you try clicking them (the ones in contents section), the titles appear a little too high, and can't be seen because of the menu. Do you have any tips on how to fix this? Thanks.

In addition, if you are feeling extra generous today, do you have and js scrollbars in mind that wouldn't break my layout? Thanks again :)

Comment: lolz @ qwertymk and cuzzea, this is not the answer BTW

Comment: @AhsanRathod yes, they're adding noise, but as you see this are only comments. Btw I use this one: http://www.000webhost.com/

Comment: @Dwarf Vader see this post, it will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: @everyone Yesy, my hosting is 000webhost.com too. It's very good considering you can't beat free. If I needed more traffic then I'd subscribe ofc...

Comment: did u try actually moving the anchors?

Comment: Moving the anchors once in a certain situation wouldn't be a problem, but I need this to be pulled from sql tables automatically each time, and I need anchors on the titles, so that I could highlight them etc. Maybe in the end I will have to, but I'm just asking here if there's a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `<div id="content">` div doesn't have enough room to get it out underneath your `<div id="shelf">`. Your solution is to increase the `top` property to push `content` down below `shelf`.

So instead of this:

`div#content {top: 155px;}`

you should have this:

`div#content {top: 190px;}`

...or whatever number you think looks good with your design. That should fix your issue for each anchor.

Comment: Thanks, it would solve my problem, if not for scrolling. If you actually implement the solution you suggested, the content would disappear before reaching id=Shelf, thus resulting in a non-good looking effect. But thanks for the tip nonetheless!

Comment: I see. The other idea you might consider is to make each major text area a `<section>` or a `<div>` with the appropriate `id` (such as `<section id="the-phone">`. Then you could apply some `padding-top` to that `section`, allowing the heading to show beneath your `shelf`.